# Is there any operator which I can use to attach 2 calculations?

Tags: c, recursion, elementary-functions

I'm doing some homework where I use only elementary operations. I need to code a function which given a positive number, calculates the whole half of that number.

My problem is at:

```
int half(int x, int y)
{
    return x == 0 ? y : half(x-1-1, y+1) , x == 1 ? y : half(x-1-1, y+1);
}
```

I don't know what if exists any operator or something that connects these calculations. On that line of code i tried to use ( , ).

I tried to replace ( , ) by using ( | ) and ( & ). But i had many errors.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int x, int y)
{
    return y == 0 ? x : sum(x+1, y-1);
}

int half(int x, int y)
{
    return x == 0 ? y : half(x-1-1, y+1) , x == 1 ? y : half(x-1-1, y+1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    int y=0;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    int z = half(x, y);
    printf("%d\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

On this code i expect the output of 6/2 to be 3 and 5/2 to be 2.

Note: The function sum although is not doing nothing i cannot remove since the homework says not to remove from the code, perhaps i need to use it.

Comment: If you know about `? :`, then you probably have learned about `if` statements already as well, right? They would be much easier to read and write.

Comment: @uneven_mark Ye i know about `if` but i still didn't learned yet in class so we can't use it.

Comment: What's the point of the second argument to `half`? This homework seems convoluted.

Comment: @JL2210 The second argument is to calculate odd number like 1, 3, 5, etc...

Comment: @vunax Usually only one number is involved in calculating a half of a number.

Comment: They're teaching recursion and ternary operator but haven't covered `if`???

Comment: the function: `sum()` is never called!  Please explain why it is even there.

Comment: the initial value of `x` is determined via the input of a value from the user.  What if the user enters -1 (or any other number less than 0)

Comment: regarding: `return x == 0 ? y : half(x-1-1, y+1) , x == 1 ? y : half(x-1-1, y+1);`  The comma ',' operator will result in the results of the first part of line being evaluated and discarded, so the actual return value will only depend on the last part of the line

Comment: if you really want to find the 1/2 value of an integer, you can simply use: `return x>>1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `||` to put these together:

```
int half(int x, int y)
{
    return x == 0 || x == 1 ? y : half(x-1-1, y+1);
}
```